# Given a multilinear polynomial $g$, and an odd function $f$ show that $\int f(x_i) \exp(-\| x \|^2) g(x-y) d x =0, \forall y,i$ where $g(x)=c$)

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, normal-distribution, convolution, gaussian-integral

Suppose that the following convolution equation holds:  for all $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and every $i =1 ..n$
$$\int f(x_i) \exp \left(- \frac{\| x \|^2}{2} \right)   g(x-y) d x =0$$

where

- $f(x)$ is an odd increasing function.
- $g$ is [multilinear polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_polynomial)  for some degree $N$

**Question:**  Can we show that $g(x)=c$ (i.e., it is a constant)?

Here is the proof for $n=1$ case:

We can write $g(x) = \sum_{i=1}^N a_i x^i$ and $g(x -y) = \sum_{i=1}  c_{i,j}  x^i y^j$ .

Now expanding the integral, we get that for all $y$
\begin{align}
0= \sum_{i+j \le N }  c_{i,j}  y^j  \int f(x) \exp(-x^2/2) x^i d x = \sum_{i+j \le N }  c_{i,j}  y^j  b_i
\end{align}
where we define $b_i = \int f(x) \exp(-x^2/2) x^i d x $.  We also not that $b_i=0$ for even $i$ and $b_i>0$ otherwise. This results in
\begin{align}
0= \sum_{i+j \le N : i \text{ is odd}}  c_{i,j}   b_i  y^j
\end{align}

Now by the identity theorem a polynomial is zero iff all of the coefficients are zero. The rest is very tedious and follows by playing with coefficients and leads to $a_i =0$ forall $i \ge 1$, which implies that $g(x) =a_0$.

**Question 2:** I wonder if there is a simpler proof too even for $n=1$?

One can also write the above in terms of expecations
\begin{align}
E[  f(Z_i) g(Z-y)] =0
\end{align}
where $Z$ is standard normal vector.